# Read all files in project folder with variable path - Python

Tags: python, operating-system, glob

Looking for thoughts on how to read all csv files inside a folder in a project.

As an example, the following code is a part of my present working code, where my 'ProjectFolder' is on Desktop, and I am hardcoding the path. Inside the project folder, I have 'csvfolder' where I have all my csv files

However if I move the "ProjectFolder" to a different Hard drive, or other location, my path fails and I have to provide a new path. Is there an smart way to not worry about location of the project folder?

```
path = r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\ProjectFolder\csvFolder' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

df_mm = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, usecols=["[mm]"]) for f in all_files),
               axis = 1, ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have dynamic and absolute path concepts, just search on google "**absolute vs relative path**"; in your case if your python file is in the ProjectFolder you can simply try this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import dirname, realpath, join


def main():
    # This is your project directory
    current_directory_path = dirname(realpath(__file__))
    # This is your csv directory
    csv_files_directory_path = join(current_directory_path, "csvFolder")
    
    for each_file_name in listdir(csv_files_directory_path):
        if each_file_name.endswith(".csv"):
            each_csv_file_full_path = join(csv_files_directory_path, each_file_name)
            
            # Do whatever you want with each_csv_file_full_path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```